# Default Batch Size in R NNet package

Tags: r, neural-networks

I'm using the nnet package in R. One of the parameters is "maxit" but there is no batch size parameter.

As such, I am confused. Is an iteration one pass through an entire data set? Or is the batch size 1 so after every additional observation and back propogation occurs to tweak the network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/nnet.pdf) say it's using [BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) algorithm to optimize the network (which should limit it's usability for big networks; even [L-BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) then has problems).

This is a batch-method (unlike Stochastic gradient descent), so it will work on complete batches (therefore no batch-size parameter).

For a good overview of optimization functions used in NN-learning, see [this paper](http://ai.stanford.edu/~quocle/LeNgiCoaLahProNg11.pdf).

Comment: How do you know it's a "batch-method"? Also, when does it do a forward/backwards optim then? After all the observations? So if  I have 1000 observations, first backwards-prop is after all 1000 observations are fed through?

Comment: Just read the first part of the paper :-) This part answers your questions. Hints: ```Batch methods, such as Limited memory BFGS``` + ```A weakness of batch L-BFGS and CG, which require
the computation of the gradient on the entire dataset
to make an update, is that they do not scale gracefully
with the number of examples```

Answer (score 0):

In the manual of the nnet package, it clarified that:

> Optimization is done via the BFGS method of optim.

So the SGD is not applicable and there is no hyperparameter batch size.